# where to add dropout layer in the model?

Tags: python, pytorch, training-data, resnet, dropout

from my understanding the use of dropout regularization randomly disables some portion of neurons in a hidden layer and it helps with the overfitting problem
I am using this implementation of resnet with pytorch and I want to add a dropout layer

```
import math
from functools import partial

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


def get_inplanes():
 return [64, 128, 256, 512]


def conv3x3x3(in_planes, out_planes, stride=1):
 return nn.Conv3d(in_planes,
                 out_planes,
                 kernel_size=3,
                 stride=stride,
                 padding=1,
                 bias=False)


def conv1x1x1(in_planes, out_planes, stride=1):
   return nn.Conv3d(in_planes,
                 out_planes,
                 kernel_size=1,
                 stride=stride,
                 bias=False)


 class BasicBlock(nn.Module):
    expansion = 1

   def __init__(self, in_planes, planes, stride=1, downsample=None):
    super().__init__()

     self.conv1 = conv3x3x3(in_planes, planes, stride)
    self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm3d(planes)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
    self.conv2 = conv3x3x3(planes, planes)
    self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm3d(planes)
    self.downsample = downsample
    self.stride = stride

def forward(self, x):
    residual = x

    out = self.conv1(x)
    out = self.bn1(out)
    out = self.relu(out)

    out = self.conv2(out)
    out = self.bn2(out)

    if self.downsample is not None:
        residual = self.downsample(x)

    out += residual
    out = self.relu(out)

    return out
class Bottleneck(nn.Module):
   expansion = 4

def __init__(self, in_planes, planes, stride=1, downsample=None):
    super().__init__()

    self.conv1 = conv1x1x1(in_planes, planes)
    self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm3d(planes)
    self.conv2 = conv3x3x3(planes, planes, stride)
    self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm3d(planes)
    self.conv3 = conv1x1x1(planes, planes * self.expansion)
    self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm3d(planes * self.expansion)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
    self.downsample = downsample
    self.stride = stride

def forward(self, x):
    residual = x

    out = self.conv1(x)
    out = self.bn1(out)
    out = self.relu(out)

    out = self.conv2(out)
    out = self.bn2(out)
    out = self.relu(out)

    out = self.conv3(out)
    out = self.bn3(out)

    if self.downsample is not None:
        residual = self.downsample(x)

    out += residual
    out = self.relu(out)

    return out


class ResNet(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self,
             block,
             layers,
             block_inplanes,
             n_input_channels=3,
             conv1_t_size=7,
             conv1_t_stride=1,
             no_max_pool=False,
             shortcut_type='B',
             widen_factor=1.0,
             n_classes=400):
    super().__init__()

    block_inplanes = [int(x * widen_factor) for x in block_inplanes]

    self.in_planes = block_inplanes[0]
    self.no_max_pool = no_max_pool

    self.conv1 = nn.Conv3d(n_input_channels,
                           self.in_planes,
                           kernel_size=(conv1_t_size, 7, 7),
                           stride=(conv1_t_stride, 2, 2),
                           padding=(conv1_t_size // 2, 3, 3),
                           bias=False)
    self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm3d(self.in_planes)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
    self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
    self.layer1 = self._make_layer(block, block_inplanes[0], layers[0],
                                   shortcut_type)
    self.layer2 = self._make_layer(block,
                                   block_inplanes[1],
                                   layers[1],
                                   shortcut_type,
                                   stride=2)
    self.layer3 = self._make_layer(block,
                                   block_inplanes[2],
                                   layers[2],
                                   shortcut_type,
                                   stride=2)
    self.layer4 = self._make_layer(block,
                                   block_inplanes[3],
                                   layers[3],
                                   shortcut_type,
                                   stride=2)

    self.avgpool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool3d((1, 1, 1))
    self.fc = nn.Linear(block_inplanes[3] * block.expansion, n_classes)

    for m in self.modules():
        if isinstance(m, nn.Conv3d):
            nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight,
                                    mode='fan_out',
                                    nonlinearity='relu')
        elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm3d):
            nn.init.constant_(m.weight, 1)
            nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)

def _downsample_basic_block(self, x, planes, stride):
    out = F.avg_pool3d(x, kernel_size=1, stride=stride)
    zero_pads = torch.zeros(out.size(0), planes - out.size(1), out.size(2),
                            out.size(3), out.size(4))
    if isinstance(out.data, torch.cuda.FloatTensor):
        zero_pads = zero_pads.cuda()

    out = torch.cat([out.data, zero_pads], dim=1)

    return out

def _make_layer(self, block, planes, blocks, shortcut_type, stride=1):
    downsample = None
    if stride != 1 or self.in_planes != planes * block.expansion:
        if shortcut_type == 'A':
            downsample = partial(self._downsample_basic_block,
                                 planes=planes * block.expansion,
                                 stride=stride)
        else:
            downsample = nn.Sequential(
                conv1x1x1(self.in_planes, planes * block.expansion, stride),
                nn.BatchNorm3d(planes * block.expansion))

    layers = []
    layers.append(
        block(in_planes=self.in_planes,
              planes=planes,
              stride=stride,
              downsample=downsample))
    self.in_planes = planes * block.expansion
    for i in range(1, blocks):
        layers.append(block(self.in_planes, planes))

    return nn.Sequential(*layers)

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.bn1(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    if not self.no_max_pool:
        x = self.maxpool(x)

    x = self.layer1(x)
    x = self.layer2(x)
    x = self.layer3(x)
    x = self.layer4(x)

    x = self.avgpool(x)

    x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
    x = self.fc(x)

    return x


def generate_model(model_depth, **kwargs):
  assert model_depth in [10, 18, 34, 50, 101, 152, 200]

  if model_depth == 10:
    model = ResNet(BasicBlock, [1, 1, 1, 1], get_inplanes(), **kwargs)
  elif model_depth == 18:
    model = ResNet(BasicBlock, [2, 2, 2, 2], get_inplanes(), **kwargs)
  elif model_depth == 34:
    model = ResNet(BasicBlock, [3, 4, 6, 3], get_inplanes(), **kwargs)
  elif model_depth == 50:
    model = ResNet(Bottleneck, [3, 4, 6, 3], get_inplanes(), **kwargs)
  elif model_depth == 101:
    model = ResNet(Bottleneck, [3, 4, 23, 3], get_inplanes(), **kwargs)
  elif model_depth == 152:
    model = ResNet(Bottleneck, [3, 8, 36, 3], get_inplanes(), **kwargs)
  elif model_depth == 200:
    model = ResNet(Bottleneck, [3, 24, 36, 3], get_inplanes(), **kwargs)

return model
```

where should place the dropout layer in this implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

In the original paper that proposed dropout layers, by Hinton (2012), dropout (with p=0.5) was used on each of the fully connected (dense) layers before the output; it was not used on the convolutional layers. This became the most commonly used configuration.
You can add dropout layer after linear layer.

```
self.fc = nn.Linear(block_inplanes[3] * block.expansion, n_classes) # add dropout after this layer.
```